# PostgreSQL hash indexes and inequality

Tags: postgresql, hashtable

The PostgreSQL documentation states that hash indexes work for equality comparisons.

```
Hash indexes can only handle simple equality comparisons. 
The query planner will consider using a hash index whenever an 
indexed column is involved in a comparison using the = operator.
```

Does this mean that it can also be used when testing for inequality? i.e. `!=`

Comment: You can test this yourself with `explain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work.

How would you use a hash table to efficiently find all items *not* equal to a certain value?